# Zoom, Meet link not working in android webview

Tags: android, webview

I am using the default web view for loading URL.
Somehow, zoom and meet links are not working with error message= "UNKNOWN_SCHEME_URL"

Zoom URL:

```
https://us02web.zoom.us/j/**ID**?pwd=wcpkf9693b95da4713f17d147fbfdf416ee1
```

Meet URL:

```
meet.google.com/mto-qcwa-***
```

Android code:

```
  webView.loadUrl(url);
```

How to enable or open it in external web browser?

Error

```
 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=zoomus://us02web.zoom.us/join?action=join&confno=....
```

Comment: Enabled JavaScript?

Comment: can you post your external web intent also?

Comment: @JohnMelodyMelissa yes    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: @SRBBans  view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your webview setup.

```
if (uri.getScheme().equals("zoomus")) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   intent.setData(uri);
   getContext().startActivity(intent);
   return true;
}
```

if it's not HTTP or HTTPS you have to explicitly specify intent and I am guessing you did it since you are getting this error. `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=zoomus://us02web.zoom.us/join?action=join&confno=....`

This means that you don't have an external intent to open it.
Check if you have installed the Zoom app.

If you have the app installed then this error won't pop up.